# Bishop-Phelps theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Bishop-Phelps Theorem: If $E$ is a Banach space and $B\subseteq E$ is bounded, closed and convex, then the linear functionals on $E$, which attain their supremum on $B$, are norm-dense in $E^*$.

Could someone give an example to show how this fails (if it does fail) when $E$ is not complete?

Comment: Google finds counterexamples if $E$ is Frechet space or complex Banach space.